# After upgrading doctrine/orm from 2.11.1 to2.16.2, I'm experiencing the following issue:

Tags: symfony6

User Deprecated: In ORM 3.0, the AttributeDriver will report fields for the classes
where they are declared. This may uncover invalid mapping configurations. To opt into the new mode today, set the "reportFieldsWhereDeclared" constructor parameter to true. (AttributeDriver.php:82 called by App_KernelProdContainer.php:175, https://github.com/doctrine/orm/pull/10455, package doctrine/orm) {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): User Deprecated: In ORM 3.0, the AttributeDriver will report fields for the classes where they are declared.
(AttributeDriver.php:82 called by App_KernelProdContainer.php:175, https://github.com/doctrine/orm/pull/10455, package doctrine/orm) {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): User Deprecated: In ORM 3.0, the AttributeDriver will report fields for the classes where they are declared. This may uncover invalid mapping configurations. To opt into the new mode today, set the "reportFieldsWhereDeclared" constructor parameter to true. (AttributeDriver.php:82 called by App_KernelProdContainer.php:175, https://github.com/doctrine/orm/pull/10455, package doctrine/orm)

But I have not found any option

Answer (score 10):

here is something that can help you.
https://github.com/doctrine/orm/pull/10455

in the doctrine.yaml file
`report_fields_where_declared: true`

As explained in the documentation
https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-bundle/en/latest/configuration.html

Comment: Funny enough, I added the above config-option and *still* get the deprecation warning ... !? Even stranger: Most of the time the warning is not there on the first load, reloading the page will suddenly display it.